# How to total the columns in a tab delimited file with unknown number of columns using split?

Tags: arrays, perl, split, csv

I have a tab delimited file which looks like:

```
__DATA__
0    0    1    0    1 ...
1    1    0    0    0 ...
1    0    0    0    0 ...
0    1    1    1    1 ...
```

There is an unspecified number of columns and rows. The columns could be as many as from 5 - 20+.

Currently I have been looking at reading the file in and splitting the lines by "\t".

Below is just a section of the code required, please note, I do use strict and -w, and declare all variables.

```
open(IN, "../../Desktop/$out") or die "Could not open $out";
my @sums;
while (<IN>) {
    if ($_ =~ /([[01]\t]*)/) {
        my @fields = split /\t/, $1;
        foreach my $i (0..$#fields) {
            $sums[$i] += $fields[$i];
        }
    } 
}
print join("\n", @sums), "\n";
```

If you can come up with a better ideal method I would be pleased to try it.
When I run this I am coming up with:

```
__OUTPUT__
0
1
1
```

When what I want is a total of each of the columns, in a total summation in a format printable to append to the bottom of each column. I have not used the split function before, so an explanation of how to use it appropriately, and access the array of arrays(?) it produces would be great. Thank you!

```
__WantedOutput__
2    2    2    1    2 ...
```

So a total for each column.

Comment: You should `use warnings` in preference to the command line `-w` switch

Comment: there is a missing closing curly brace after the foreach block

Comment: I don't understand what `/([[01]\t]*)/` is supposed to do, but because of the `*` it will match a zero-length substring and so any string will pass the test.

Comment: There are no zero length substrings, I was just hoping to grab only the '0's and '1's, again, if you have a better solution for that, go ahead, I am willing to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. To make the @sums survive the loop, you have to declare it before it starts. If you want the output on one line, don't join with a newline, but with a tab:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @sums;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^[01] (?: \t [01] )+ $/x) {
        my @fields = split;
        for my $i (0 .. $#fields) {
            $sums[$i] += $fields[$i];
        }
    }
}
print join("\t", @sums), "\n";

__DATA__
0   0   1   0   1
1   1   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0
0   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, this prints a running total of all the columns: 1 .. n-1. Whereas I am looking for a total of each column. For example:
0    0    1    1   
1    1    1    1
0    1    1    0

1    2    3    2

Comment: @CG3: I'm getting `2 2 2 1 2` as the output, which is clearly the total for each column. What do you mean?

Comment: Also, I didn't think it needed mentioning, but there is column and row headings, so the lines don't begin with [01], hence just taking the 0s and 1s from the line, as these are not in the headings.

Comment: Well, I didn't think it needed mentioning, but you can't use the code given for free as it was. You have to adjust it :-)

Comment: That is not the output I am getting. I am getting a running count across all columns. The tail end of my output for example is: 185
186
187
188
189
190
191
192
193
194

So it is essentially a count?

Comment: Yes, of course I was adjusting it, I kept my regex and followed your answer logically to fit my script ;) don't worry! But thank you

Comment: @CG3: Without seeing the input, I can't tell. Try running it with smaller data where you can easily verify the result.

Comment: I have one such input file open in a spreadsheet, so I know what the totals should be. What does your sample output look like exactly once printed?

Comment: Here it is run through `xxd`: `00000000: 3209 3209 3209 3109 320a                 2.2.2.1.2.`

Comment: Apologies, I had forgotten to adjust my split statement to match yours, this works perfectly, thank you!